# Wrapper function in C++ with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: c++

I am working with a certain C API which has a certain `CallMethod` function (it is the Python API, but it should be irrelevant). Like the following:

```
 void * C_API_CallMethod(void *h1, void *h2, ...);
```

I would like to encapsulate this into a C++ library with some fancy types. In particular, all my objects are `FancyHandler` objects which have a certain method `getPointer`.

Something like that:

```
//template<>?
FancyHandler CallMethod(const FancyHandler &first, const FancyHandler &second, 
            const FancyHandler& ...list) {

    return C_API_CallMethod(first.getPointer(), second.getPointer(), 
        (...).getPointer(), nullptr);
}
```

I was looking into variadic template, but is not exactly what I want. Or it seems a bit too complex because the type is known, and the number of arguments not. Variadic seems more general and I don't know how to constrain those things.

Using `cstdarg` seemed a step backwards and I was expecting to avoid that... moreover, I haven't used it in a long time and am not eager to start again. I would prefer a more C++ solution.

At this point, I am not able to compile the source, as the compiler complains about the ellipsis because obviously, it is not valid source.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: It might be easier to write a FancyHandler casting method to `void*` that the compiler can use to convert them.

Comment: In C and C++, it is impossible to pass down variadic arguments of a function to another, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That's not exactly correct. You can't pass them into another `...` function, but you can pass it as a `va_list`.

Comment: @ooga I meant "to another variadic function".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant @ooga The API is C and is not under my control. You mean that I am forced to use `va_list`? Even under that situation, I do not know see how to manage the C++ arguments

Comment: @MariusSiuram **if** you have a function that accepts a `va_list`, then you can "forward" the arguments of a true variadic function to it. If you haven't got any functions that take a `va_list`, then it will **not** be possible to forward variadic arguments to them. At all.

Answer (score 0):

With variadic templates, you could try the following approach (wrap the getPointer):

```
void * C_API_CallMethod(void *h1, void *h2, ...);

struct FancyHandler
{
    void* getPointer() const { return nullptr; }
};

void* getPointer(const FancyHandler&first) {
    return first.getPointer();
}

template<typename... Args> 
void pass(Args&&... args) {
    C_API_CallMethod(args...);
}

template<typename... Args> 
void CallMethod(const FancyHandler& h1, const FancyHandler& h2, Args&&... args) {
    pass(getPointer(h1), getPointer(h2), getPointer(args)...);
}
```